# Capture any occurrence of word in a text; RegEx; Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words  that I want to cross-reference with a bunch of texts, and if a word from the search string is present in the text, I want to retain the text.

```
search_string = ['Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly']
```

My code so far is:

```
retained_texts = []
for text in full_text:
    if set(text) & search_string:
        retained_texts.append(' '.join(text))
```

Here, `full_text` is a list of lists and `text` is a list of words.

This method has a very low level of accuracy, because it retains only texts where the `Good`, the `Bad`, and the `Ugly` are separate words. However, it rejects instances where they are imbedded in other words.

E.g.,

Instances like `Goodwill`, `Ugly-duckling`, `BadBoy`, `Good-Bad-Ugly` etc. are all rejected, while I definitely need them to be retained.

I would assume this could be solved with regex, but my I frankly don't know how.

Comment: Would `Good` count as being in `Goods`?

Comment: @zondo Yes, it would. In other words any string that contains the combination of characters from the search sting would count.

Comment: What about case?  Does `Good` count as being in `goods`?

Comment: @zondo yes, the case matters (i.e., `Good` is not equal to `goods`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with following regular expression:

```
re.match('(Good|Bad|Ugly)', text)
```

So your full code would look something like this:

```
import re

search_string = ['Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly']
pattern = '({0})'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, search_string)))
retained_texts = []
for text in full_text:
    if re.search(pattern, text):
        retained_texts.append(' '.join(text))
```

**UPDATE:** As comments point out there is a problem if `search_string` contains dots, parenthesis or any other characters that need to be escaped within regular expressions. This can be fixed by calling `re.escape` when pattern is being constructed, I've edited the example above accordingly.

Comment: Useful to note this is case sensitive so Good does not equal good. Also returns None if regex is not matched but answers the question nicely.

Comment: ▲ for forming alteration using string methods. I liked this approach But you should note that when a text is very large enough and your list is also significant this is very inefficient approach . By checking this [example](https://regex101.com/r/dN2wW9/1) you will realize why I said that. Also when the list of words include a dot `.` your search string will form a regex in which it will be **metacharacher**, [example](https://regex101.com/r/dN2wW9/2).

Comment: This works nice! However, if the word is in parentheses – it does not return an object. E.g., `re.match(pattern, '(Bad)')` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this:

```
search_list = ['Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly']
retained_texts = []
for text in full_text:
    if any(search in word for word in text for search in search_list):
        retained_texts.append(' '.join(text))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could flatten the full_text first, then do a regex match:

```
>>> import re
>>> search_string = ['Good', 'Bad', 'Ugly']
>>> full_text = [['yes','no'],['Bad','Ahh'],['Goodwill','Ugly-duckling','BadBoy','Good-Bad-Ugly']]
>>> [j for j in [i for f in full_text for i in f] if re.findall('Good|Bad|Ugly',j)]
['Bad', 'Goodwill', 'Ugly-duckling', 'BadBoy', 'Good-Bad-Ugly']
```